# Grouping monthly data in a dataframe to show row sub-totals

Tags: python

I have the following table where Date is the index column:

| Date | ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 10 | 40 |
| 2021-01-02 | 20 | 15 |
| 2022-01-01 | 10 | 40 |
| 2022-01-02 | 20 | 15 |

I want to add row-subtotals to show yearly summation:

| Date | ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 10 | 40 |
| 2021-01-02 | 20 | 15 |
| 2021 Subtotal | 30 | 55 |
| 2022-01-02 | 20 | 15 |
| 2021-01-02 | 20 | 15 |
| 2022 Subtotal | 40 | 30 |

I tried the following code:

```
df.groupby(level='Date').transform("sum")
```

However I am getting the following error:
DateFormatError: invalid date '2022 Subtotal'

Any alternatives to achieve similar results?

Comment: your index is a datetime format

Comment: "2022 Subtotal" is a string and the rest is a data format. Change all the items in the " 'DATA" columns to strings before use.

Comment: I recommend you to do a yearly some instead of changing your datetime format

Comment: How can I do a yearly sum? I have just started to learn python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# grouper for years
# convert to datetime and extract year
# convert to string and add ' Subtotal'
group = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year
         .astype(str)
         .add(' Subtotal')
         )

# perform groupby.sum using the above grouper
# concatenation with original data
# sorting by year to move the subtotals below their respective data
out = (pd.concat(
       [df,
        df.groupby(group)
          .sum().reset_index()])
         .sort_values(by='Date',
                      key=lambda x: x.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False),
                      kind='stable'
                      )
)
```

Output:

```
            Date  ColA  ColB
0     2021-01-01    10    40
1     2021-01-02    20    15
0  2021 Subtotal    30    55
2     2022-01-01    10    40
3     2022-01-02    20    15
1  2022 Subtotal    30    55
```

Comment: Thank you! This was great. Could you please also walk me through what the code is doing?

Comment: I added some more comments, I suggest you try to run the individual parts to see how this works. Let me know if you have specific questions!

Comment: @mozway I'm struggling to understand the sorting process. `str.extract` with your pattern will extract the year of each row. So, the years gets ordered in the correct order, makes sense. But why exactly we can be sure that the Dates which are followed by `-` (and then other numbers) are placed before the years followed by a space and `Subtotal`?

Comment: This is because sorting preserves the original order and when we concat the total is after the original data. Try to swap them in concat for a reverse order! Actually the safest is to add `kind='stable'`